# Double integral with assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is this how I should describe my functions?

```
Integrate[ArcTan[y/x], A, Assumptions ->  1<(x^2+y^2)<4 && 0<y<x]
```

I'm studying for the Wolfram Cloud by cell phone. I have trouble adding the correct symbols

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As it can be easily read in the documentation:

```
Integrate[ ArcTan[y/x], {x, y} \[Element] 
           ImplicitRegion[1 < (x^2 + y^2) < 4 && 0 < y < x, {x, y}]]

(* 3 \[Pi]^2/64 *)
```

Note that you know the region of integration. So you can define the region by using `ImplicitRegion`:

```
ImplicitRegion[1 < (x^2 + y^2) < 4 && 0 < y < x, {x, y}]
```

This the region to be calculated the integral of `ArcTan[y/x]`:

```
RegionPlot[1 < (x^2 + y^2) < 4 && 0 < y < x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

and these are graphs of the function in the region:

```
GraphicsRow[(#[ArcTan[y/x], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 <= y <= x && 1 < (x^2 + y^2) < 4]] & /@   
{Plot3D, DensityPlot}), ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: But this result is an integral double?

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it is a "double integral" since the `ImplicitRegion` has dimension 2.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) change  to polar coordinates:

[image]

$f(x,y)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho  \sin (\phi )}{\rho  \cos (\phi )}\right)=\tan ^{-1}(\tan (\phi
   ))=\phi$ for: $\phi >0$

$1\leq \rho ^2\leq 4$ and $0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi }{4}$

we have:

$$\int _1^2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\phi  \rho d\phi d\rho$$

```
Integrate[ϕ*ρ, {ρ, 1, 2}, {ϕ, 0, Pi/4}]]

(*3 π^2/64 *)
```